# $R^2$ but using the average of the linearized data

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients

Suppose you have a set of data $y_i$ and the corresponding linearized data $f_i$ obtained through linear regression.

Set:
$$(R')^2=\frac{\sum_i (f_i-\bar{f})^2}{\sum_i (y_i-\bar{y})^2},$$
that is a fraction with the same denominator as the usual regression coefficient $R^2$ but at the numerator you put the average $\bar{f}=\sum_i f_i/n$ of the linearized data instead of the average $\bar{y}=\sum_i y_i/n$ of the real data.

Has this coefficient $(R')^2$ any significance? How it compares to $R^2$?

Comment: the mean of the linearized data is the same as the mean of the real data (so long as your model has an intercept).

Comment: Can you please provide an explanatory link or a short explanation about why?

Comment: for sure https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/469212/proof-that-the-mean-of-predicted-values-in-ols-regression-is-equal-to-the-mean-o

Comment: Great! Many thanks!